# Run PHP/Javascript/AJAX Application On Schedule/Cron?

Tags: javascript, php, command-line, cron, scheduled-tasks

I have an application that I need to deploy that is a mix of pure PHP, JavaScript, jQuery, and AJAX. It runs flawlessly on all machines when called in a browser. Unfortunately, I also need to deploy this application to a machine that won't be able to run a browser.

Just running the file using PHP will output the resulting file, but does not execute any of the Javascript.

What are my options to get this task running? The machine will have access to xampp, but not to a browser.

Edit: the application grabs data from MSSQL, uses Javascript to turn that data into charts, uses an AJAX call to save those files to disk, and then calls another PHP script to mail a copy of the resulting files.

Comment: Could you please tell what your script does actually?

Comment: @Tarun I've edited to show this information.

Comment: You should be able to generate the charts from the data using only PHP, and then you're good to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what your exact Javascript needs are, but unfortunately, if your application truly depends on a browser (and can't be ported to something more appropriate for the constraint), you will need to "fake" the browser somehow.  Here are a few options.

1. [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) is basically a headless Webkit engine (think Chrome or Safari).
2. [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) for a Java based solution, supported/developed by Mozilla
3. [Other rabbit holes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headless_browser) (Wikipedia/Headless Browser)
4. [NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/) offers a non-browser, headless, Javascript specific option, but will require your code to be more robust and generic than many code bases initially are when originally coded for browsers.

Comment: I'll take a look at these and see if any of these will work. Are these in order of best-to-worst, or are they all about the same?

Comment: "Best-to-worst" is subjective; I put them in somewhat random order not knowing your problem very well, but, especially given your edit, I might consider PhantomJS first for easier portability given the _current_ state of your code, and NodeJS second for a longer-term more robust solution set.

Comment: Ultimately, I went with a lightweight headless browser, and it is working far better than I anticipated. +1, accepted, and Favorited for future use.